# package with pip install does install it but same package with setup.py does not get installed

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to install some packages using *pip*, which is working fine but if I try to install it using `setup.py` then it does not install it.

For example:

```
pip install ruamel-yaml-clib==0.2.7
```

does install the package.

But having the same package in `setup.py`, for example:

```py
install_requires=['ruamel-yaml-clib==0.2.7']
```

and running:

```
python setup.py install
```

throws below error:

```
Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ruamel-yaml-clib==0.2.7')
```

I tried to search the difference but did not found anything.

I am using *Python 3.8*.

Comment: Which command did you run when you say that you tried to "_install it using `setup.py` then it does not install it_"?

Comment: can you try `install_requires=['ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.7']` (with dots)?

Comment: @sinoroc I am doing `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to spell it [`ruamel.yaml.clib`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml.clib/) with dots `.` instead of dashes `-` in the `setup.py`? I think that in principle it should not matter, both spellings should be equivalent, even though the normalized name is indeed the one with the dashes `-`: `ruamel-yaml-clib`.

Anyway, calling `python setup.py install` is deprecated, you should not run this command unless you strictly can not avoid it. The recommendation is to always install with *pip* (or any other modern installer) instead: `python -m pip install .`.

***References***:

- https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml.clib/
- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/name-normalization/
- https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html
- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/commands.html